# How to disable prefetch in VueJS PWA?

Tags: vue.js, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, vue-cli, workbox

When you generate a PWA app using `vue ui` you can expect the following behavior.
All files you have in your **dist** folder are precached by browsers.
In other words, when you navigate to your app a browser will quietly download all the files and cache it for further use.

The problem here is that browsers will also download **async chunks** which could never be used by a user. For example, I have an **admin-settings** route and a regular user does not need to download it at all.

Now I'm trying to disable this behavior, here's modified **vue.config.js** file:

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.plugins.delete('prefetch-index')
    config.plugins.delete('preload-index')
  },
  pwa: {
    workboxOptions: {
      exclude: [/.*/],
      runtimeCaching: [{
        urlPattern: new RegExp('^https://example.com.*'),
        handler: 'CacheFirst',
        options: {
          cacheableResponse: {
            statuses: [200]
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

Right now everything works as expected and browsers do not prefetch resourses. The problem, however, is that when I upload a new version of a file the app is not updated. Browsers still use the previos version of the file.

I'm stuck, any advice, good sirs?

**P.S. Figured it out.**

This line caused `index.html` to be also cached.

`urlPattern: new RegExp('^https://example.com.*')`

After changing it everything works as expected.

`urlPattern: new RegExp('^https://example.com/.+')`

Now the **problem** is that the old version of a cached file is not deleted from cache. The size of cache would grow a lot with each new deployment.

Any advice?